# Sorting on a boolean field

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have a model that looks something like this

```swift
@Model
class TodoTask {
    var title: String
    var isDone: Bool
    var expectedOn: Date
}
```

I want to render a list of Tasks such that when `isDone == true` the item appears at the bottom of the list.

I have a Query binding similar to the one below but the boolean field errors with "No exact matches in call to initializer"

```swift
@Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\TodoTask.expectedOn, order: .reverse), SortDescriptor(\TodoTask.isDone )]) var todoTasks: [TodoTask]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you specify the order explicitly? `SortDescriptor(\TodoTask.isDone, order: .forward)`

Comment: @Alexander This will lead to another error that TodoTask needs to conform to NSObject :(. I guess this is because SortDescriptor is using NSSortDescriptor under the hood.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Interesting. Does SwiftData use the Objective C runtime the way that CoreData does? I've never used it before.

Comment: @Alexander No I don't believe so but it uses Core Data under the hood. Note though that SortDescriptor is not a SwiftData but a Foundation type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you are not doing something wrong and this should be fixed in SwiftData. A workaround for now that, unfortunately, would require a more complicated solution would be

Remove the `isDone` property from the query

```
@Query(sort: [SortDescriptor<TodoTask>(\.expectedOn, order: .reverse)]) var todoTasks: [TodoTask] = []
```

Add a computed property on `TodoTask` that can be used for sorting, for instance

```
var isDoneSort: UInt8 {
    isDone ? 1 : 0
}
```

and then add a new array property to sort on this and use this new array in your view instead of the query property

```
var sortedTasks: [TodoTask] {
    todoTasks.sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\TodoTask.isDoneSort))
}
```